# PHP - Add new object to every array of objects

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Consider this array of objects in PHP:

```
 array:2 [
      0 => array:4 [
        "Row_Id" => 256
        "Start_Date" => "2020-05-16"
        "account_code" => ""
        "caller_number" => "452"
        ]
    
      1 => array:4 [
        "Row_Id" => 257
        "Start_Date" => "2020-05-16"
        "account_code" => ""
        "caller_number" => "42"
        ]

      2 => array:4 [
        "Row_Id" => 258
        "Start_Date" => "2020-05-16"
        "account_code" => ""
        "caller_number" => "428"
        ]
    ]
```

I want to add `"callee_number:100"` in every array so my output should look like these:

```
     array:2 [
          0 => array:5 [
            "Row_Id" => 256
            "Start_Date" => "2020-05-16"
            "account_code" => ""
            "caller_number" => "452"
            "callee_number" => "100"
            ]
        
          1 => array:5 [
            "Row_Id" => 257
            "Start_Date" => "2020-05-16"
            "account_code" => ""
            "caller_number" => "42"
            "callee_number" => "100"

            ]

          2 => array:5 [
            "Row_Id" => 258
            "Start_Date" => "2020-05-16"
            "account_code" => ""
            "caller_number" => "428"
            "callee_number" => "100"
            ]
        ]
```

I have taken the above input array in $get variable. Now I am calling `array_push` to append `callee_number` to every array:

```
  array_push($get,[
   'callee_number':'100'
    ]);
```

Also tried using `array_merge` but `callee_number` is not getting appended. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the following array:

```
$array = [
    [
        "Row_Id" => 256,
        "Start_Date" => "2020-05-16",
        "account_code" => "",
        "caller_number" => "452",
    ],
    [
        "Row_Id" => 257,
        "Start_Date" => "2020-05-16",
        "account_code" => "",
        "caller_number" => "42",
    ],
    [
        "Row_Id" => 258,
        "Start_Date" => "2020-05-16",
        "account_code" => "",
        "caller_number" => "428",
    ],
];
```

Native PHP

```
$array = array_map(function ($item) { return $item + ['callee_number' => 100]; }, $array);
```

Using collections

```
$array = collect($array)->map(function ($item) { return $item + ['callee_number' => 100]; })->toArray();
```

Using PHP 7.4 shorthands

```
$array = array_map(fn($item) => $item + ['callee_number' => 100], $array);
// Or
$array = collect($array)->map(fn($item) => $item + ['callee_number' => 100])->toArray();
```

Comment: Upvoted. You're missing the assignment parts of the `array_map` versions, though (it doesn't modify the array in place).

Answer (score 0):

To add or modify an element in each sub-array you would do this:

```
foreach ($get as &$g) {
  $g["callee_number"] = 100;
}
```

Or this:

`for ($c = 0; $c < count($get); $c++) {
$get[$c]["callee_number"] = 100;
}`

Comment: not sure what you're saying with the text but the example is right.

Comment: In OP's second example they're showing the impossible situation of having two "callee_number" elements in each object.

Comment: @joshstrike - i don't have two things called "callee_number" in the same array. Read the question again.

Comment: Ah. Apologies. My eyesight is not so good. I saw "caller_number" and "callee_number" as the same. The code in my answer will work. I'll remove the other part.